# Windows 10 or Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot

I used Ubuntu and then now my Windows 10 and Ubuntu doesn't work and my hard drive and it keeps taking me back to the bios system.

If I don't press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>del</kbd> button it takes me to the Ubuntu and then says install Ubuntu. When I select install it long log comes up and it just freezes.

Please help it's urgent and my Windows boot manager is gone too.

[image]

Comment: You can upload the picture to imgur (or some other file sharing site) and link it here, that would be helpful. As it is, there's not a whole lot you've described that we can go on.

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0):

The first line in the picture `initram's unpacking failed` may be caused by faulty RAM. Reboot and press `ESC` on the boot menu and run a memory test.

Comment: Faulty RAM will often result in a specific faulty RAM message being shown at boot time. Unfortunately the boot screen goes by so quickly that it is impossible to read the boot message, but if you can see it flashing by on the screen you can stop the screen by quickly pressing the Pause/Break key, write down the RAM message, and then restart the screen by pressing the Pause/Break key again.